# TensorFlow and the MNIST data set

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, mnist

First of all: I'm completely new to Machine Learning and TensorFlow - I'm just playing around with this technology for a few weeks - and I really like it.

But I have (maybe a simple) question about the MNIST data set in combination with TensorFlow: I'm currently working through the "MNIST for ML Beginners" tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners). I fully understand how the whole thing works, and what I accomplish with the source code.

My question is now the following:
Is it possible to see the individual weights parameters for each pixel? As far as I understand I can't access the individual weight parameters directly for each pixel, because the tf.matmul() operation returns me the sum over all weight parameters for a given class.

I want to access the individual weight parameters, because I want to see how these values are changing through the training process of the Neural Network.

Thanks for your help,

-Klaus

Answer (score 1):

You can get the actual weights by just doing something like:

```
w = sess.run(W, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
print w.shape
```

If you want the per pixel results, just do a element-wise multiply of batch_xs * w (reshaped appropriately.)